# React-bootstrap not allowing `import {components}` syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

This is kinda weird. It works with other projects, but not with React-Bootstrap. For example;

```
import {Jumbotron, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
```

both give me a `Invalid argument must be an array` in `all.js:12` file. However, importing like this works:

```
var Jumbotron = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron');
var Button = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Button');
```

Sure I can use this, but it's more efficient to declare an array of components I want. Why is React-Bootstrap not supporting something so trivial?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Answer (score 0):

`react-bootstrap` currently [don't support ES6 modules natively](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html#es6).

In other words, *you need to do some work* to be able to use ES6 imports. One way is to use a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) that will [transpile your code from ES6 to CommonJS modules](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/).

Comment: I am using babel. I have a `babelrc` file with `stage-0` in it, I use plenty of other ES6 stuff in my code.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem at [webpackbin here](http://www.webpackbin.com/NyN9ymtMG). Should be fine with `stage-0` and `es2015`