# React-Bootstrap navbar won't render; type should not be null, undefined, boolean or number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is a bit absurd. I've been testing components straight from the React-Bootstrap site and some fail while others succeed. Here's my code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

var Jumbotron = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron');
var Button = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Button');
var Nav = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar').Nav;
var NavItem = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar').NavItem;
var NavDropdown = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar').NavDropdown;
var Navbar = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar');
var MenuItem = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Button').MenuItem;

export class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

   constructor() {
     super();

 }

     return (
      <div>
      <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
       <Navbar.Header>
         <Navbar.Brand>
           <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
         </Navbar.Brand>
         <Navbar.Toggle />
       </Navbar.Header>
       <Navbar.Collapse>
         <Nav>
           <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
           <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
           <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
             <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
             <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
             <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
             <MenuItem divider />
             <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
           </NavDropdown>
         </Nav>
         <Nav pullRight>
           <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
           <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
         </Nav>
       </Navbar.Collapse>
     </Navbar>
     </div>
     );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is literally copied straight from [the Navbar example code](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars-mobile-friendly) with a wrapping div. It gives me 13 copies of `React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of`App`.` error and one of `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of`App``.

However, if I try the [Jumbotron demo code](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#jumbotron), it works fine; it renders the Jumbotron without any issues. Am I importing something wrong in the `import` statements? This is literally the simplest of examples, how can it be going so wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, deleting my node-modules folder and reinstalling with `npm i` fixed that issue. Not sure what was wrong with my initial install, but wiping it seemed to work out, so hey, why not.

Answer (score 0):

This is due the reason that you `Navbar.Header` and any other item that you use with `Navbar` is undefined, however your `Navbar` is defined. This may be due to the reason that you babel is not properly resolving them

Try using you import differently as

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, Button, Jumbotron, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

I think this should work for you.

Comment: I'd love to import like that, however the bloody [react-bootstrap components won't allow themselves to be imported like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833129/react-bootstrap-not-allowing-import-components-syntax). So I had to try a more explicit way.

Comment: Well I import the react-bootstrap components like this only. are you using anything like webpack or browserify

Comment: I'm using webpack, yes. I have a `.babelrc` file with `stage-0` in it, if that affects anything.

Comment: Try adding es2015 as a preset in it too. I don't remember which package to install for its dependency. Also try using react as React.Component {}

Comment: My .babelrc already has that, and stage-0, and `react`. It also has `"plugins": ["syntax-async-functions","transform-regenerator"]`. What do you mean by using react as React.Component? Right now I make my class with: `export class App extends React.Component<any, any> {}`